# Aggregating ArrayType Rows consists of Floats using Higher Order Functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am on Databricks and I have a table which has a `values` column rows consist of arrays. The arrays themselves are consist of floats. I need a new column which sums up those arrays.

I was inspired by a Databricks blogpost: https://databricks.com/blog/2017/05/24/working-with-nested-data-using-higher-order-functions-in-sql-on-databricks.html

I tried this:

```
SELECT   key,
         values,
         REDUCE(values, 0, (value, acc) -> value + acc) summed_values_simple
FROM     nested_data
```

But it doesn't work. The error message is about:

```
due to data type mismatch: argument 3 requires int type, however, 'lambdafunction' is of float type.
```

If I use int types then it works! But I don't work with integers. I am trying to figure out how to approach this problem.

Here is the reproducible table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY VIEW nested_data AS
SELECT   id AS key,

         ARRAY(CAST(RAND(1) * 100 AS FLOAT), CAST(RAND(2) * 100 AS FLOAT), 
         CAST(RAND(3) * 100 AS FLOAT), CAST(RAND(4) * 100 AS FLOAT), CAST(RAND(5) * 100 AS FLOAT)) AS values

FROM range(5)
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
key values                           summed_values_simple
0   [26.3, 11.6, 66.0, 8.7,  47.6]    160.2
1   [66.0, 8.7,  47.6, 91.4, 6.4]     220.1
2   [8.7,  47.6, 91.4, 6.4,  70.6]    224.7
3   [91.4, 6.4,  70.6, 41.3, 19.8]    219.5
4   [6.4,  70.6, 41.3, 19.8, 12.0]    150.1
```

Perhaps I shouldn't stick to higher-order-functions and there is another nice way. Thank you for giving suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Higher order functions in Spark SQL are rather picky about the types at this point and you have to make sure that both inputs and outputs conform to the expected types.

Here it will be enough to `CAST` the accumulator first.

```sql
SELECT *, aggregate(
  values,
  CAST(0 AS double),  -- Accumulator has to be of the same type as the input
  (value, acc) -> value + acc) summed_values_simple
FROM nested_data
```

Comment: Great you are awesome!